# Python Plotly fill between two specific lines

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I've seen this question asked before in some form or the other, but never answered entirely, so i'll try my luck.

In a plot with several traces, i’m trying to fill the areas between two specific lines that i choose.
The desires effect, achieved with matplotlib.pyplot looks like this:

[image: desired plot]

where the cyan and orange areas are filled between their respective trends, and up/down to the red line. The black line is unrelated to those filled areas, but should be plotted along with the red line regardless.

I tried achieving this with Plotly’s fill: 'tonexty', but this doesn’t work out well because due to the randomness of the data, the nearest Y is sometimes the black line and not the red.

I can achieve this with pyplot's fill_between function:
`plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2)`

Where it can be used as:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

series1 = pd.Series(np.random.randn(100), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=100))

series2 = series1 + np.random.randn(len(series1))

positive_contribution = series2 + 0.5
negative_contribution = series2 - 0.5

plt.plot(series1, color='black')
plt.plot(series2, color='red')
plt.fill_between(series2.index, series2, negative_contribution, color='cyan', alpha=0.2)
plt.fill_between(series2.index, series2, positive_contribution, color='orange', alpha=0.2)
```

I’d love to hear of a solution / workaround for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to achieve this is to add traces in the right order. An important thing I noticed is that `"tonexty"` actually fill the space between the current trace and the trace that was previously added in the 'trace storage'.

The first option is thus to add your traces from top to bottom or bottom to top (I chose bottom to top, this is partially extracted from the [plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/filled-area-plots/)):

```py
# the cyan trace, without color filling
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=series2.index,
        y=negative_contribution,
        fill=None,
        mode="lines",
        line_color="cyan",
    )
)

# the red trace, with cyan color filling up to the previously added trace
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=series2.index,
        y=series2,
        fill="tonexty",
        fillcolor="cyan",
        mode="lines",
        line_color="red",
    )
)

# the orange trace, with orange color filling to the previously added trace (the red one).
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=series2.index,
        y=positive_contribution,
        fill="tonexty",  # fill area between trace0 and trace1
        mode="lines",
        line_color="orange",
    )
)

# add the black trace.
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=series1.index,
        y=series1,
        fill=None,
        mode="lines",
        line_color="black",
    )
)
```

A problem with this solution is that the cyan color filling legend will be merged with the red trace, which can be confusing.

Another solution is to always add the trace you want to fill between just before the `tonexty` trace. You should use a transparent color, use `showlegend=False` for any trace but the final trace added (if a trace need to be repeteadly added):

```py
# add a transparent red trace not visible on legend.
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=series2.index,
        y=series2,
        fill=None,
        mode="lines",
        line_color="rgba(0,0,0,0)",
        showlegend=False,
    )
)
# add orange trace
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=series2.index,
        y=positive_contribution,
        fill="tonexty",
        mode="lines",
        line_color="orange",
    )
)
# re add the red trace, but visible this time, as this is the last one
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=series2.index,
        y=series2,
        fill=None,
        mode="lines",
        line_color="red",
    )
)
# add the cyan trace
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=series2.index,
        y=negative_contribution,
        fill="tonexty",
        mode="lines",
        line_color="cyan",
    )
)
# finally add the black trace
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=series1.index,
        y=series1,
        fill=None,
        mode="lines",
        line_color="black",
    )
)
```

It is more controllable, however, adding multiple time the same trace could add spurious interactive effect.

Comment: "An important thing I noticed is that "tonexty" actually fill the space between the current trace and the trace that was previously added in the 'trace storage'."

- This is exactly what i was looking for. I assumed 'tonexty' just meant 'to the nearest'.
I found your 2nd solution better as I would like the user to be able to turn off the display for the contributing/fill traces, and therefore would rather have the 'fill' variable on them and not the main trace have it.
Thanks!